# Prefix filename with foldername without loop

Tags: powershell

A request to help a friend led me to google and then to powershell.  I'm about 3 hours into knowing powershell existed (whole new world!) and already this forum got me very close to what I need with some searching but not all the way.

I am looking to dynamically add the folder name to each filename in a given set of sub folders.

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + $_.Name}
```

- this works but gets stuck in a loop on some files (not sure why only some) and continuously adds the folder name to the file name over and over until it bins out

In an attempt to stop the loop I tried echo on/off in different places and then looked at Get-ChildItem and -Exclude which got me to -

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude LAL-* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + $_.Name}
```

- this seems to work well but I'd like to make it dynamic so the exclusion is $_.Directory.Name* but I can't make it work?

Apologies it's so 'noddy' but any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that Get-ChildItem (alias dir) is also providing directory names to the pipeline. This can be avoided by using the `-File` switch.

I am not sure how to do this without a loop. `ForEach-Object` might reasonably be interpreted as a loop construct. When you are confident that the files are being renamed as you wish, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet.

```
(dir -Exclude "$((Get-Location | Split-Path -Leaf) + '*.*')") |
ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($_.Directory.Name + $_.Name) -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, -WhatIf seems to be very useful and potentially would have stopped me screwing a load of filenames in error :-) 

With the WhatIf in place the destination looks correct, however, when I actually run it without I get stuck in the loop still

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand "stuck in the loop" yet. Is the display frozen? Does it endlessly spout error messages? How many files are there in this directory?

Comment: @ lit - My apologies to you.  I must have made an error last time but having deleted and copied your code again it works! Thank you!  It would be a useful addition to -Exclude files names that already start with the folder name but this can easily be worked around.

Comment: I think I understand what you were saying about using `-Exclude`. Does this work in the way you expect?

Comment: I tried 
$filelist = Get-ChildItem -File -Where {$_.FileName -notlike "*$_.Directory.Name*"} 
$filelist |
but it errors with 'a parameter cannot be found'.  I can make a specific exclusion work like -Exclude LAL-* but not when the exclusion is variable like the directory name - hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Ian - That's a nice idea, but `Get-ChildItem` does not have a `-Where` parameter and `$_` refers to the object from the previous command in the pipeline. See the parameters using `help Get-ChildItem -Full`. I altered the `-Exclude` parameter to use the current directory name. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @ lit - that is absolutely bang on!  'Powershell for beginners' book has arrived so I can hopefully be a bit more self sufficient in future - really appreciate your help, thanks!!